# JOIN the same table twice and select a pair

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

```
staff (enum,ename,title)
101,Zhivago,Doctor
102,Welby,Doctor
103,Jekyl,Doctor
104,Caligari,Doctor
105,Nightingale,Nurse
106,Ratchet,Nurse
```

and

```
expertise (enum,code)
101,4001
101,4002
101,4003
101,4004
101,4005
101,4006
102,4002
102,4003
102,4006
103,4001
103,4006
103,4004
104,4004
104,4006
105,4002
105,4003
105,4004
105,4006
106,4001
106,4002
106,4003
106,4004
106,4005
106,4006
```

How do I get pairs of doctor and nurse (enum, ename, title; enum,
ename, title) who share at least one expertise.

Also pairs of doctor and nurse (enum, ename, title; enum,
ename, title) with the exact same expertises.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @MediaPlayer . . . You have asked more than one question so I'm voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listagg()` window analytic function together with an `self-join` for expertise table, and leave pairs only by using `having` clause

```
select listagg(e.enum||','||s.ename||','||s.title,';') 
        within group (order by e.enum) as "Grouped Results"
  from staff s
  join expertise e 
    on e.enum = s.enum
  join expertise e2 
    on e2.enum = s.enum and e2.code = e.code
 group by e.code
 having count(1)>1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/YUAZU91041)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this SQL will get the desired results:

Part 1:  *How do I get pairs of doctor and nurse (enum, ename, title; enum, ename, title) who share at least one expertise.*

Explanation:  select all doctors matched to nurses on any expertise; filter to distinct results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s1.enum as doctor_enum,
    s1.ename as doctor_ename,
    s1.title as doctor_title,
    s2.enum as nurse_enum,
    s2.ename as nurse_ename,
    s2.title as nurse_title
  from staff as s1
  inner join expertise as e1 on e1.enum = s1.enum
  inner join expertise as e2 on e2.code = e1.code
  inner join staff as s2 on s2.enum = e2.enum
  where s1.title = 'Doctor'
    and s2.title = 'Nurse';
```

Part 1 results:

```
doctor_enum doctor_ename    doctor_title    nurse_enum  nurse_ename nurse_title
101 Zhivago Doctor  105 Nightingale Nurse
102 Welby   Doctor  105 Nightingale Nurse
103 Jekyl   Doctor  105 Nightingale Nurse
101 Zhivago Doctor  106 Ratchet Nurse
103 Jekyl   Doctor  106 Ratchet Nurse
102 Welby   Doctor  106 Ratchet Nurse
104 Caligari    Doctor  105 Nightingale Nurse
104 Caligari    Doctor  106 Ratchet Nurse
```

Part 2:  *Also pairs of doctor and nurse (enum, ename, title; enum, ename, title) with the exact same expertises.*

Explanation:  select same as above, but check if any of the doctor expertise do not match the nurse and vice versa.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s1.enum as doctor_enum,
    s1.ename as doctor_ename,
    s1.title as doctor_title,
    s2.enum as nurse_enum,
    s2.ename as nurse_ename,
    s2.title as nurse_title
  from staff as s1
  inner join expertise as e1 on e1.enum = s1.enum
  inner join expertise as e2 on e2.code = e1.code
  inner join staff as s2 on s2.enum = e2.enum
  where s1.title = 'Doctor'
    and s2.title = 'Nurse'
    and not exists (
          SELECT *
            FROM expertise e1
            WHERE e1.enum = s1.enum
              AND e1.code NOT IN (
                    SELECT code FROM expertise e2 WHERE e2.enum = s2.enum
              )
     )
    and not exists (
          SELECT *
            FROM expertise e2
            WHERE e2.enum = s2.enum
              AND e2.code NOT IN (
                    SELECT code FROM expertise e1 WHERE e1.enum = s1.enum
              )
     );
```

Part 2 results:

```
doctor_enum doctor_ename    doctor_title    nurse_enum  nurse_ename nurse_title
101 Zhivago Doctor  106 Ratchet Nurse
```

Here is a schema script for anyone using this answer in the future:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    `enum` int,
    `ename` nvarchar(50),
    `title` nvarchar(50)
);

 INSERT INTO staff VALUES
   (101,'Zhivago','Doctor'), 
   (102,'Welby','Doctor'), 
   (103,'Jekyl','Doctor'), 
   (104,'Caligari','Doctor'), 
   (105,'Nightingale','Nurse'), 
   (106,'Ratchet','Nurse');

CREATE TABLE expertise (
   `enum` int,
   `code` int
);

INSERT INTO expertise VALUES
  (101,4001),
  (101,4002),
  (101,4003),
  (101,4004),
  (101,4005),
  (101,4006),
  (102,4002),
  (102,4003),
  (102,4006),
  (103,4001),
  (103,4006),
  (103,4004),
  (104,4004),
  (104,4006),
  (105,4002),
  (105,4003),
  (105,4004),
  (105,4006),
  (106,4001),
  (106,4002),
  (106,4003),
  (106,4004),
  (106,4005),
  (106,4006);
```

Hope this helps.